# Lua: Random: Percentage

Tags: lua

I'm creating a game and currently have to deal with some `math.random`ness.

As I'm not that strong in Lua, how do you think

- Can you make an algorithm that uses `math.random` with a given percentage?

I mean a function like this:

```
function randomChance( chance )
         -- Magic happens here
         -- Return either 0 or 1 based on the results of math.random
end
randomChance( 50 ) -- Like a 50-50 chance of "winning", should result in something like math.random( 1, 2 ) == 1 (?)
randomChance(20) -- 20% chance to result in a 1
randomChance(0) -- Result always is 0
```

However I have no clue how to go on, and I completely suck at algorithms

I hope you understood my bad explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 9):

With no arguments, the `math.random` function returns a number in the range [0,1).

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> =math.random()
0.13153778814317
> =math.random()
0.75560532219503
```

So simply convert your "chance" to a number between 0 and 1:  i.e.,

```
> function maybe(x) if math.random() < x then print("yes") else print("no") end end
> maybe(0.5)
yes
> maybe(0.5)
no
```

Or multiply the result of `random` by 100, to compare against an int in the range 0-100:

```
> function maybe(x) if 100 * math.random() < x then print(1) else print(0) end  end                                                                             
> maybe(50)
0
> maybe(10)
0
> maybe(99)
1
```

Yet another alternative is to pass the upper and lower limits to `math.random`:

```
> function maybe(x) if math.random(0,100) < x then print(1) else print(0) end end
> maybe(0)
0
> maybe(100)
1
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `math.random(0,100)` will return a number between 0 to 100, so 1 out of 101 possible numbers, therefore x in your maybe function is no longer a percentage, but 1 in a 101 chance.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't mess around with floating-point numbers here; I'd use `math.random` with an integer argument and integer results.  If you pick 100 numbers in the range 1 to 100 you should get the percentages you want:

```
function randomChange (percent) -- returns true a given percentage of calls
  assert(percent >= 0 and percent <= 100) -- sanity check
  return percent >= math.random(1, 100)   -- 1 succeeds 1%, 50 succeeds 50%,
                                          -- 100 always succeeds, 0 always fails
end
```